# VUE | Javascript : How to access a key as a date format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, html-table

I have an array of dates, I also have an object that looks like this:

```
[
{'2020-04-01': {name: 'john', sex: 'male'}, 'id': 222},
{'2020-04-02': {name: 'jane', sex: 'female'}, 'id': 111}
]
```

Now for some reason, I used html table instead of vue datatable and when I access the date key, nothing shows. The rendering goes like this..

```
...
...
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in body_data">
        <template v-for="date in date_range">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td> //works fine
            <td>{{item.date.name}}</td> //shows nothing, also no error
        </template>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it because I cant have a date as key? Or did I just call it wrongly?

**Sorry for bad english**

Comment: You need to convert the dates to a string and then access the items as `item[date].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be:

```
<td>{{item[date].name}}</td>
```